# define const generics associated with outer const generic

Tags: rust

I've situation where I want to have size of inner const generics defined struct to have size twice the outer one.

```rust
struct Inner<const DOUBLED_SIZE: usize>;
impl<const DOUBLED_SIZE: usize> Inner<DOUBLED_SIZE> {
    pub fn print(&self) {
        println!("val: {}", DOUBLED_SIZE);
    }
}

struct Outer<const SIZE: usize> {
    pub inner: Inner<SIZE>,
    // want to have size of Inner double of Outer
    // uncomment following line
    //pub inner: Inner<2*SIZE>,
}

fn main() {
    let outer = Outer::<40> { inner: Inner {} };
    outer.inner.print();
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently requires the [`generic_const_exprs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/generic-const-exprs.html) nightly-only feature flag; it is not yet supported in stable Rust.